# attach image to poll choice in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, polling

I have a polls module that comes with drupal 7 enabled, But I need to attach an image filed to a choice, not to the node itself.
is there a way to add this image?

Comment: You probably don't want to use the polls tag. That's for questions which are soliciting a list of opinions, not for questions about polling software.